# Accessing the texture's rectangle in a cocos2d sprite

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have `CCSprite` which (for reasons I'll gloss over here) has some padding around its edges. I'm creating the sprite from a sprite sheet, and it is continuously animating. Here, I've added a semi-transparent blue sprite to show the `contentSize` of the sprite. I've also turned on `CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW` in order to draw borders around (both) sprites:

[image]

Thus, the blue box represents the `boundingBox` / `contentSize` properties of `CCSprite`. texture. This is correct, desired functionality.

However... as you can see, `CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW` is able to recognize the actual edges of the drawn texture. I'd like to access the actual "drawn area" (eg, as a `CGRect`). In other words: I want to be able to detect if the user touched **on the unit** as opposed to simply in the blue box (`boundingBox`).

How can I access this `CGRect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the debug draw code I found this:

```
#if CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW == 1
    // draw bounding box
    CGPoint vertices[4]={
        ccp(_quad.tl.vertices.x,_quad.tl.vertices.y),
        ccp(_quad.bl.vertices.x,_quad.bl.vertices.y),
        ccp(_quad.br.vertices.x,_quad.br.vertices.y),
        ccp(_quad.tr.vertices.x,_quad.tr.vertices.y),
    };
    ccDrawPoly(vertices, 4, YES);
#elif CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW == 2
    // draw texture box
    CGSize s = self.textureRect.size;
    CGPoint offsetPix = self.offsetPosition;
    CGPoint vertices[4] = {
        ccp(offsetPix.x,offsetPix.y), ccp(offsetPix.x+s.width,offsetPix.y),
        ccp(offsetPix.x+s.width,offsetPix.y+s.height), 
            ccp(offsetPix.x,offsetPix.y+s.height)
    };
    ccDrawPoly(vertices, 4, YES);
#endif // CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW
```

It looks like you may be able to get what you want from the sprite's `quad` property. Or perhaps its the second solution, because I don't know what cocos2d means by bounding box and texture box here.

Comment: I already spent a while mucking around with this and have had poor luck so far, which is why I ended up posting here in hopes that there was an easy solution... appreciate the tip though!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I came up with, as a function in my custom subclass of `CCSprite`:

```
// In local space
- (CGRect)hitArea {
  CGPoint bl = CGPointMake(MIN(_quad.tl.vertices.x, _quad.bl.vertices.x), MIN(_quad.bl.vertices.y, _quad.br.vertices.y));
  CGPoint tr = CGPointMake(MAX(_quad.tr.vertices.x, _quad.br.vertices.x), MAX(_quad.tl.vertices.y, _quad.tr.vertices.y));
  return CGRectMake(bl.x, bl.y, tr.x - bl.x, tr.y - bl.y);
}

// In game space, like how .boundingBox works
- (CGRect)hitBox {
  return CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.hitArea, [self nodeToParentTransform]);
}
```